# How to access state value from one component to other function(not component) which is in separate file? React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native, components

This is my Home Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { getData } from '../../../util/network';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: 1,
    };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    const val = await getData();
  }

  render() {
    return() {
      // jsx stuffs
    }
  }
}
```

This is a file called network.js: // which is a function

```
export const getData = () => {
  const { page } = this.state; // this is undefined now
  const url = `http://randomuser.in/${page}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error:', error);
    });
};
```

How to access state value of **page** in my network.js file?

Comment: If you want access to the state, your getData() function needs to be a method inside your component class. Component state only exists within that component.

Comment: Or pass the state as an argument to `getData()`

Comment: is there any method? to access from separate file

Comment: As far as I know you can't access the components state from some random unrelated JS file. Either pass it as an argument, or embed the `getData` function in the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `page` state as a parameter to your function :

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const val = await getData(this.state.page);
}
```

Note that I replaced `componentWillMount` by `componentDidMount` which is prefered for doing async actions.

```
export const getData = (page) => {
  const url = `http://randomuser.in/${page}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error:', error);
    });
};
```

Comment: If i put console, to page in network.js it tell me "undefined".

Comment: Have you passed the argument to getData like this : `getData(this.state.page);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be depending on `this.state` in your function. Its not a good practice. You should just pass the parameters/arguments you will need in that function.

**Example**

```
const val = await getData(this.state.page);
```

---

```
export const getData = (page) => {
  // use page argument that passed
  //...
};
```

Comment: If i put console, to page in network.js it tell me "undefined".

Comment: Be sure that you passed the argument to the function and be sure its defined with some value.